# Fatal error: public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 126

Tags: wordpress

Migrei meu site Wordpress para outra hospedagem, fiz tudo certinho, porém esta ocorrendo este erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function untrailingslashit() in /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/wp-includes/option.php:126 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/wp-includes/default-constants.php(138): get_option('siteurl') #1 /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/wp-settings.php(255): wp_plugin_directory_constants() #2 /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/wp-config.php(102): require_once('/storage/ssd3/4...') #3 /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/storage/ssd3/4...') #4 /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/storage/ssd3/4...') #5 /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/index.php(17): require('/storage/ssd3/4...') #6 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 126

Comment: A mensagem fala que a função `untrailingslashit` não está definida. Tem como por o conteúdo do arquivo `option.php`? E também se ele inclui algum outro arquivo?

Comment: Verificou a permissão dos arquivos, estão em 755?

Comment: Também, verificou o arquivo .htaccess? Desativou os plugins ou templates para ver se é algum deles que tá conflitando?

Comment: Vou verificar, porem eu baixei os arquivos do meu site e não tem mais como eu desativar os plugins porque não tenho acesso ao site

Comment: Eu mudei a versão do php para a antiga versão e agora o erro virou apenas isso:  Call to undefined function untrailingslashit() in /storage/ssd3/451/2091451/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 126

Comment: @Stéfano Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`untrailingslashit` é uma função padrão do WordPress então isso significa que algum arquivo está faltando ou corrompido.

Uma coisa que pode ter acontecido é que alguns arquivos falharam na hora de subir pro novo servidor. Isso é muito comum quando as transferências são feitas via FTP.

1. Faça um novo backup dos arquivos da instalação atual.
2. Baixe uma nova cópia do WordPress [aqui](https://wordpress.org/download/)
3. Substitua os arquivos do seu servidor ***exceto***:

   3.1 a pasta **wp-content**

   3.2 o arquivo **wp-config.php**

   3.3 outros arquivos que não sejam nativos do WordPress.